# JavaFX list databinding

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I have a model class that is running in separate thread (implements Task). It has an `ArrayList` that is updated during infinite loop.

```
private List<ClientSession> clientSessions = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the controller class I need to have unidirectional binding for this list that has `ChangeListener` and is showed in the TableView.

Could you help me to understand how to do it in the best way (binding)?

I have figured out how to make content binding.

*In model class I have added:*

```
public ObservableList<ClientSession> clientSessions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

*In controller class I have added:*

```
private ListProperty<ClientSession> clientSessionListProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
clientSessionListProperty.bindContent(commandCenterNio.clientSessions);
```

But this doesn't solve the issue with tableview. How to use the `TableView` in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need an intermediate property, the [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) is "bindable" by default, as it tells you whenever a change was performed on the list:

> A list that allows listeners to track changes when they occur.

All you have to do to give the `ObservableList` of the model directly for the listview by calling [setItems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setItems-javafx.collections.ObservableList-).

**I have prepared an example:**

The example has a model that implements `Runnable` (**but notice that the fact, that it updates its list in an infinite loop makes absolutely no difference in terms of the solution**), which has an `ObservableList` of `ToDo` objects, which has to `Property` to display on the `TableView`. In `Main` the model is filled with some initial data and a `ListView` is displayed with the data. The GUI also has some controls to add new items to the model through its buffer.

*SampleModel.java*

```
public class SampleModel implements Runnable{

    // Listen to this list
    public ObservableList<ToDo> toDoList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // Buffer to be used to store new elements until the thread wakes up
    private BlockingQueue<ToDo> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<ToDo>(1000);

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        while(true){
            // Drain the buffer to the ObservableList
            queue.drainTo(toDoList);

            // Sleep a bit
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
        }

    public void updateBuffer(ToDo newItem){
        queue.offer(newItem);
    }
}
```

*ToDo.java*

```
public class ToDo {

    private StringProperty task = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public StringProperty taskProperty() {return task;}

    private ObjectProperty<Importance> importance = new SimpleObjectProperty<Importance>();
    public ObjectProperty<Importance> importanceProperty() {return importance;}

    public ToDo(String task, Importance importance){
        this.task.set(task);
        this.importance.set(importance);
    }


    enum Importance {
        DONTCARE, SHALL, MUST, FIRSTPRIO;

          @Override
          public String toString() {
            switch(this) {
              case DONTCARE: return "I don't care";
              case SHALL: return "It shall be done";
              case MUST: return "It must be done";
              case FIRSTPRIO: return "I will die if I do not do it";
              default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
          }
    }

}
```

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            SampleModel model = new SampleModel();
            model.toDoList.addAll(new ToDo("Brooming", ToDo.Importance.DONTCARE),
                    new ToDo("Taking a nap", ToDo.Importance.FIRSTPRIO),
                    new ToDo("Cooking", ToDo.Importance.MUST),
                    new ToDo("Wash the car", ToDo.Importance.DONTCARE),
                    new ToDo("Pay the bills", ToDo.Importance.SHALL));

            TableView<ToDo> tableView = new TableView<ToDo>();

            TableColumn<ToDo, String> colTask = new TableColumn<ToDo, String>();
            colTask.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("task"));

            TableColumn<ToDo, String> colImportance = new TableColumn<ToDo, String>();
            colImportance.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().importanceProperty().get().toString()));

            tableView.getColumns().addAll(colTask, colImportance);

            tableView.setItems(model.toDoList);

            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.setPrefSize(180, 15);
            ComboBox<ToDo.Importance> cb = new ComboBox<ToDo.Importance>();
            cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(ToDo.Importance.FIRSTPRIO, ToDo.Importance.DONTCARE, ToDo.Importance.MUST));

            Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
            btnAdd.setOnAction(e -> model.updateBuffer(new ToDo(textArea.getText(), cb.getValue())));

            hbox.getChildren().addAll(textArea, cb, btnAdd);
            root.getChildren().addAll(hbox, tableView);

            Thread thread = new Thread(model);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();


            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```